# Hangman - my first Clojure code

Tags: beginner, clojure, hangman

This is my first attempt at Clojure! Apart from all game related issues, how is my code? Is there anything I can do to make it more idiomatic?

```
(ns hangman.core                                                                                    
  (:import (java.net ServerSocket Socket SocketException)                                                
           (java.io PrintWriter InputStreamReader BufferedReader))                                       
  (:gen-class))                                                                                          

(defn guess [guess word]                                                                                 
  (apply str (map #(let [x (str %)] (if (.contains guess x) x "*")) word)))                              

(defn listen [port]                                                                                      
  (new ServerSocket port))                                                                               

(def word "clojure")                                                                                     

(defn conn-handler [conn]                                                                                
  (let [in (:in @conn)                                                                                   
        out (:out @conn)]                                                                                
    (.println out "Welcome to this simple hangman game.")                                                
    (def the-guess (atom ""))                                                                            
    (loop [conn conn]                                                                                    
      (.println out (str "Guess the word: " (guess @the-guess word)))                                    
      (.flush out)                                                                                       
      (let [g (str @the-guess (.readLine in))                                                            
            res (guess g word)]                                                                          
        (if (= word res)                                                                                 
          (do                                                                                            
            (.println out res)                                                                           
            (.println out "Correct!")                                                                    
            (.flush out))                                                                                
          (do                                                                                            
            (reset! the-guess g)                                                                         
            (recur conn)))))))                                                                           

(defn -main [& args]                                                                                     
  (println "Server running…")                                                                            
  (with-open [server (listen 3456)]                                                                      
    (loop []                                                                                             
      (let [client (.accept server)                                                                      
          in (BufferedReader.(InputStreamReader.(.getInputStream client)))                               
          out (PrintWriter. (.getOutputStream client))                                                   
          conn (ref {:in in :out out})]                                                                  
        (println "Client connected")                                                                     
        (doto (Thread. #(conn-handler conn)) (.start))                                                   
        (recur)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bunch of random observations

- avoid `def` as a non-top level form e.g. in `(def the-guess (atom ""))`, prefer `let` bindings
- there's no need to use a ref for the connection, as it never changes after creation. Prefer a simple map, which also enables you to use plain destructuring instead of using `let` to extract its components:

```
(defn conn-handler [{:keys [in out] :as conn}] ...)
...
conn {:in in :out out}]
(println "Client connected")
(doto (Thread. #(conn-handler conn)) (.start))
```

- instead of using interop to interact with the in/out streams you could use a more idiomatic `(binding [*out* out *in* in] (println ...) (read-line))`
- you loop over the `conn`, but you always recur over the very same object. You can remove `conn` from the loop/recur forms
- if you follow the `binding` approach as described above, but within the anonymous function that you use to initialize the thread, you could completely remove the `conn` name from the whole code:

```
(defn conn-handler [] (println "...") ...)

(doto (Thread. #(binding [*in* in *out* out] (conn-handler)) (.start))
```

- there's no need to use an atom for the guess, just use plain recursion:

```
(loop [the-guess ""]
...
  (recur g))
```

The following code contains the revised `conn-handler` and `-main` functions, including all the suggestions above, plus the cosmetic change of using the threading macro `->` instead of the `doto` form, which seems a bit clearer:

```
(defn conn-handler []
  (println "Welcome to this simple hangman game.")
  (loop [the-guess ""]
    (println (str "Guess the word: " (guess the-guess word)))
    (flush)                                                                                       
    (let [g (str the-guess (readLine))                                                            
          res (guess g word)]                                                                          
      (if (= word res)                                                                                 
        (do                                                                                            
          (println res)                                                                           
          (println "Correct!")                                                                    
          (flush))                                                                                
        (do                                                                                            
          (recur g))))))                                                                           

(defn -main [& args]                                                                                     
  (println "Server running…")                                                                         
  (with-open [server (listen 3456)]                                                                      
    (while true                                                                                             
      (let [client (.accept server)                                                                      
            in (BufferedReader.(InputStreamReader.(.getInputStream client)))                               
            out (PrintWriter. (.getOutputStream client))]                                                                  
        (println "Client connected")                                                                     
        (-> #(binding [*in*  in
                       *out* out]
               conn-handler)
            (Thread.)
            (.start))))))
```

Comment: I have some trouble getting it to work with the threading macro as you suggested.